# How to combine various measures into a single measure?

Tags: statistics, vectors, algorithms, machine-learning

So I'm trying to understand the intuition behind the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915362) which is used to combine several scores into a single score.

Namely, this part:

```
SQRT(wa * A^2 + wb * B^2 + wb * C^2)
```

Why take the square root of the weighted sum of squares? I had previously been looking at the weighted sum model (i.e. `(wa * A + wb * B + wb * C)`) but the accepted answer above works better at combining scores for my domain

What's the intuition behind doing this? Does it have a name?

Answer (score 1):

This is done many times in statistics. Its purpose is to transform the sum model back to it's original units, since the original components were squared. This is similar to how the standard deviation is the square root of the variance which is the average of the squared differences from the mean.

This also corresponds to the Euclidean norm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm